# How can I get router traffic from my vpc on amazon web service?

Tags: router, amazon-web-services, traffic

I would like to get router traffic from my router inside my vpc in amazon web service, using tcpdump.

Currently I'm trying to do this on my EC2 instance using ubuntu.

Could someone help me please?

Comment: You can't. You need to run tcpdump on the router itself to monitor router traffic.

Comment: do you know how could I log in the vpc router?

Comment: You should read [AWS Routing 101 – Matt Adorjan – Medium](https://medium.com/@mda590/aws-routing-101-67879d23014d)

Comment: This question sounds like it may be a case of [XY](http://xyproblem.info), where you are asking about your attempted solution, rather than asking about the original problem.  What problem are you actually trying to solve by accessing "router traffic?"

Comment: I want to use an intrusion detection system to analyze network traffic data between all EC2 instances

Comment: is there a way to login into the vpc router? from there I could use tcpdump

Answer (score 2):

A VPC doesnt really have a router. At least not one you could do this with. You should look at [VPC flow logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/flow-logs.html).

Comment: can't I log in the vpc router table? I think all the traffic goes through this router

Comment: Your VPC has an internet gateway, and this isnt something you can log in to.

Comment: There is also NAT instances, if you are referring to that, thats different, but you would have had to set that up. If you used the managed NAT service you cant log in there either.